# Why no UDP connection via browser even with HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, udp, websocket

Why can we not have UDP connection between a browser and a server? Why is TCP connection possible (via WebSockets) and UDP not?

Comment: Because websockets are built on top of TCP.

Comment: chrome packaged apps have access to an API for UDP io.

Comment: Can you explain more so I can google it? What is that API? Are you talking about webRTC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML5 does not allow arbitrary TCP connections.

Instead, web sockets is a special new protocol built on on TCP that allows bidirectional communication.

Similarly, WebRTC is a special new protocol built on UDP that allows peer-to-peer communication.

Allowing arbitrary socket connections would be a *major* security hole.

Comment: True, but even websocket is TCP, and no UDP

Comment: @Cgraphics: It wouldn't make sense to allow UDP web sockets.  Web sockets rely on properties of TCP like ordering and guaranteed delivery.

Comment: Note: WebRTC is only implemented on top of UDP in Firefox.

Answer (score 3):

You can get access to UDP using WebRTC, which is available in the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox. This lets you do direct browser - browser connections without needing to go via the server, amongst other things.

Comment: Nice can we make UDP connections between a browser to a server too? I guess right?

Comment: actually, RTC still needs a server to handshake, which is not clear in from the text shown...

Comment: I believe it is possible, yes. You will need to have a server side implementation of the WebRTC protocols. I have heard of such things being talked about, but I don't know of any actual implementation.

Comment: yup, webRTC uses ICE http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Connectivity_Establishment to negotiate a the connection, which can be implemented on a server side.

using libjingle https://developers.google.com/talk/libjingle/ - you *should* be able to create a client/server udp connection though it might be quite challenging.